# Metrics and Spinors

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, dirac-equation, spinors

this might be better posed in mathematics but I'll ask here anyway.

So the Lagrangian for the spinor field can be viewed as follows. Let $(M,g,\nabla)$ denote a locally Minkowskian spacetime, Where $\varphi:U\rightarrow \varphi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ denotes an chart on an open set containing some point $p$ of interest.

Let $s=(\varphi,\psi\circ\varphi): U\rightarrow \varphi(U)\times\mathbb{C}^d$ define a $d$ component spinor $\psi$ locally defined on some coordinate patch containing $p$ (here $\psi$ is a section of a locally trivialised spinor bundle; of course one could generalise to a more abstract fibre).

Then I can define a Dirac Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}: \varphi(U)\times\mathbb{C}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_D = \bar{\psi}(\varphi(p))(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \psi(\varphi(p))
\end{equation}

Now in effect, the only information from the manifold needed to feed into this Lagrangian is a single point - I do not need any other forms of data to retrieve this number (except $m$ which is a "constant").

Compare this to the Lagrangian of the metric: A metric requires three pieces of data to compute at a point:

\begin{equation}
g(\cdot,\cdot)(\cdot) : \Gamma(TM\otimes TM)\times U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

Now when I define the Einstein Hilbert Lagrangian, I must consider terms of form $\sim\partial ^2g, (\partial g)^2$.

The point being, that I can consider a tensor field $g(X,Y):U \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, but actually looking at the metric without specifying these vector fields is problematic as I need more than just a point to work with its lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L}_g \sim \partial^2 g + (\partial g)^2 
$$

So to well pose this Lagrangian, I ultimately need to consider two vector fields as data, as well as the point.

Does this mean we should really consider the Lagrangians for the scalars/spinors and metrics as in different classes of Lagrangian, based on the amount of data required in each case?

Comment: Actually, the Dirac Lagrangian written here is not diffeomorphism invariant. In order to get this the spin connection is required. So it will not just depend on points of the manifold.

Comment: Sticking in a factor $\sqrt{-g}$ then? Or send $\partial \rightarrow D$ eg Fock Ivanenko derivative $D = \partial + \omega \gamma\gamma$

Comment: But the point is the actual fields themselves don't depend on the same number of parameters - the metric (graviton) depends on two vectors, as opposed to the fermion $\psi(x), x=\phi(p)$

Comment: As you apparently refer to the Lagrangian of the free gravitational field the curvature scalar being an expression like $\partial^2 g + (\partial g)^2$, it's the double contracted Riemann tensor, it is a scalar which does not act anymore on tangential vectors. For the contraction one might need some tangential vectors (on which is summed over), which can be chosen freely, i.e. $\partial_i$ or more generally without changing $R$.  Even more exactly $L_{EH}\sim R\sqrt{-g}$  is a scalar density which transforms like $L'_{EH}=| det \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}|L_{EH}$.

Comment: But that is the same as saying the metric requires vectors, which spinors don't. Hence they require different amounts of data?

Comment: Clearly the components of the metric are functions of the coordinates only, and so categorising them as fields make sense (has a value for each point on the manifold). but these are the same as the metric eating two tangent vectors evaluated at a point. In our case one can write in the standard way $R(X,Y,Z,W)=g(R(X,Y)Z,W)$ where $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$ is the Riemann operator. I still need more information to construct the Ricci scalar than just points on the manifold (ie trace of the above)...

Comment: A Lagrangian is mathematically  always a scalar density, so it does not need tangential vectors and it always transforms like $L' = |\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}| L$ to make the action $S= \int L d^{n}x$ invariant. But already L is completely tangential vector independent. This is true for every $L$. If you like you can consider the integrant as 4-form: $L d^{n}x$, in order to evaluate the integral $S$ you need to evaluate the 4-form on tangential vectors which are actually given by the volume element. This is also valid for all  $L d^{n}x$, whether Diracian or Hilbert-Einstein or other.